# Laravel 5: How to orderBy, depending on whereHas?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have 2 Laravel models, `Classes` and `Subjects`. Each Class belongs to a Subject.

I'd like to do a query, which sorts and returns the classes depending on whether their subject's ID is within a given array of IDs.

E.g. I can use the code below successfully to get the list of classes, which have the relevant subject IDs.

However, I can't figure out how to get ALL classes (i.e. no filter), and just sort so that the classes which have the relevant subjects are first, followed by other classes.

One approach is to create 2 different Collections, and `->merge` them, but that then gets tricky when trying to paginate.

Thanks for your help!

```
Classes::whereHas('subject',function($q) use ($subject_list) {
    $q->whereIn('id', $subject_list);
})->get();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could perform a [`leftJoin`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#joins) to get all classes (i.e. no filter), and just sort so that the classes which have the relevant subjects are first

```
Classes::leftJoin('subjects', function ($join) use ($subject_list) {
            $join->on('classes.subject_id', '=', 'subjects.id')
                 ->whereIn('subjects.id', $subject_list);
        })
        ->orderBy('classes.subject_id')
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

`whereHas()` will not help you here. You can use `sortByDesc()`:

```
$classes = Classes::all();
$classes->sortByDesc(function($i) use($subject_list) {
    return in_array($i->subject_id, $subject_list);
});
```

Or you could execute two queries and merge results:

```
$classes = Classes::whereIn('subject_id', $subject_list)->get();
$classesNotIn = Classes::whereNotIn('subject_id', $subject_list)->get();
$classes->merge($classesNotIn);
```

I've tested both approaches and they work, but you'll need to create Paginator manually in both cases.